# Malware in Word document

Tags: node.js, security

TL:DR? Word Documents are packages, is it dangerous to upload them to the server then?

I'm developing an application in Angular 4, and Node JS, that at some point allow users to upload files, that should be only images, pdf's and Word documents.

Front end validation goes well, until node rejects a Google Docs file exported as .docx and says the file is actually a zip (application/zip).

Okay, perfectly normal, but native Word documents, have a different MIME type, so:

Should I enable the upload of zip files?

Considering that I could successfully use a docx as a zip, add a script and go back to use it as a docx file, should I have any security worries?

Is it possible to include malicious software *inside* a docx file and somehow use/run it on the server side?

Am I worrying about nothing?

Comment: Word VBA/COM macros are a vector for malware, yes. Consider ILOVEYOU: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILOVEYOU - this predates the PKZIP-as-container-for-OOXML file format, btw.

Answer (score 1):

There is no danger in a Word file on your server UNLESS you open it with Word or some other tool that processes it and essentially "runs it".  Then, that provides a vector for macro malware that could be run when the file was opened in some program that might runs those macros.

Just storing it and enabling others to download it does not put your server at risk in any way.  A plain file that you just store or send to others upon request is just a bucket of bits that doesn't "run" any code.

If you are providing a storage and retrieving mechanism, you may want to prevent yourself from becoming a distribution mechanism for malware by using some sort of scanner on all files that are uploaded to you such that you can filter out files that might harm someone else who downloads them and does attempt to open/run them.